# How to make a MessageBox pop up only if the value in ComboBox changes

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to make the MessageBox pop up whenever the value in the combobox changes, instead, it currently pops up on the load and then when the value changes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Public Class DropDownBox

Private Sub DropDownBox_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dropSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    dropSource.Add("", "")
    dropSource.Add("1", "1")
    dropSource.Add("2", "2")
    dropSource.Add("3", "3")
    dropSource.Add("4", "4")
    dropSource.Add("5", "5")
    dropSource.Add("6", "6")
    dropSource.Add("7", "7")
    dropSource.Add("8", "8")
    dropSource.Add("9", "9")
    dropSource.Add("10", "10")

    cbox.DataSource = New BindingSource(dropSource, Nothing)
    cbox.DisplayMember = "Value"
    cbox.ValueMember = "Key"

    cbox.Text = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub cbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbox.TextChanged

    If cbox.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Are you sure?")
    Else

    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you for your help.

Please let me know if you need any additional information on this subject, I've searched all over and haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: Are you putting something the `cbox.Text` in the design, so when you press the run button is `cbox.Text` filled

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I'm just referencing to the ComboBox value as text and set it as Nothing on load, so that any change supposed to trigger the MessageBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event `Combobox.SelectionChangeCommitted` perfectly fit your requirement without extra workarounds.

> The SelectionChangeCommitted event is **raised only when the user
>   changes** the combo box selection

[ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
Private Sub cbox_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                                      Handles cbox.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim combobox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If combobox.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Are you sure?")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's true, but sometimes you need the event even when the ComboBox is changed by code, just not while the control is initializing. Thanks, though. I wasn't aware of that event.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks, I forget to change `if..else`. By using `sender`, you ensure that correct control is used. This habit can save sometimes hours ;)

Comment: True. I do that any time I have a routine handling events for more than one object.

Answer (score 2):

I like Youssef's answer, and use that when I have multiple objects, such as an array of controls, that share the same event handler. The downside is that you don't get to identify the event handler in the object's events in the comboboxes at the top of the editor, nor see the routine identified as the handler in the code.

I like this approach:

```
Private Sub cbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbox.TextChanged
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then Return

    If cbox.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Are you sure?")
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

You can also use cbox.IsHandleCreated

Answer (score 1):

I think the value is changing already on loading form.

Anyway here is my idea

Firstly, Remove the event handler, so this line

```
Private Sub cbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbox.TextChanged
```

should be

```
Private Sub cbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

Secondly, Add the handler again at the end of the form_load by this line

```
AddHandler cbox.TextChanged, AddressOf cbox_TextChanged
```